# how can I limit selected item of dropdown with bootstrap4

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a problem with my drowpdown I can't customize selected items I tried to search how can I limit dropdown choices by I didn't found a solution.
so i have 20items to show in a dropdown ,my goals is to show just 5 items and a selected item called "showMore" that after I click into it, display me a popup contains the rest of my items for example :
mylist=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t]
my_showing_list_in_dropdown=[a,b,c,d,e,showMore]

```
<div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light dropdown-toggle dropbtn" data-toggle="dropdown" (click)="onUpdateData()">
                </button>

                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdwn" >
                  <a
                    class="dropdown-item p-1 small "
                   *ngFor="let x of mylist" (click)="selectedItem(x,index)"
                    >
                    <span class="mr-2"
                      ><small style="color: gray;"
                        >{{x}}</small></span
                    >

                  </a>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <a
                  class="dropdown-item p-1 small "
                  (click)="creation()"
                  >
                  <span class="mr-2"
                    ><small style="color: gray;"
                      >SHOW More</small></span
                  >

                </a>
                </div>
              </div>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you provide a working demo please ?

Comment: ok sir : https://stackblitz.com/github/imaneribas/dropdown/tree/master/drop